# Using os.system mkdir with variables in python

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to use os.system in python2 to create a new directory stored under a variable name, but instead of using the string that the variable is set to, the bash call uses the variable name and creates a dir in the pwd.

```
from os import system
outputDir = ~/Desktop/test
system('mkdir outputDir')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: Note that the answers initially on offer wouldn't work if your directory name includes spaces or literal wildcard characters. But then, using `os.system()` to create directories in Python is wrong in and of itself -- that's what `os.mkdir()` is for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `os.mkdir`! This is a better choice than `os.system`, since you get errors directly as exceptions. To expand the `~` you can use `os.path.expanduser`. This way, you can use the path also in `open`, etc.

```
outputDir = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/test')
os.mkdir(outputDir)
```

Comment: Note: he won't get automatic `~` expansion with this.

Comment: And you could toss in an `os.path.expandvars` if you want environment variable expansion.